# Using a Datastax Cassandra ResultSet with Java 8 Parallel Streams - Quickly

Tags: java, list, cassandra, resultset, datastax

I am fetching a lot of rows from Cassandra using the Datastax Driver and I need to process them as quickly as possible.

I have looked into using `List::parallelStream().forEach()` which seems great at first since `ResultSet` acts a lot like a `List`, but sadly I am unable to use `parallelStream()` directly on `ResultSet`. To get this to work I first have to use `ResultSet::all()` which really is slow - I assume it iterates over each element.

```
ResultSet rs = this.getResultSet(); // Takes <1 second

// Convert the ResultSet to a list so as I can use parallelStream().
List<Row> rsList = rs.all(); // Takes 21 seconds

rsList.parallelStream().forEach(this::processRow); // Takes 3 seconds
```

Is there any faster way I can process each row of the result set?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how much time does sequential processing of rList take? Looking at your timing figures your bottleneck is not the processing of the rows but their retrieval. So parallelizing row processing will give you a rather small improvement. To me it seems you should look into optimizing your query/schema/cluster setup/network.

Comment: I come from a PHP background so I'm used to the Result set containing the rows once execute () is called. Is that not the case here?

Comment: Independent of the driver you are using the problem is the same: You submit a query via the driver to C*; C* processes the query and calculates the rows of the result set; C* sends back the result rows to the driver (in pages as @doanduyhai pointed out). The client can start processing rows as soon as the driver makes the first row available to it (`one()` returns the first row). So you can start processing rows in parallel to C* sending more rows, effectively parallelizing the process. But overall you can never be faster than the time it takes for C* to send you the last row of the result.

Comment: And what you are suggesting is that the time it takes C* to send to rows across is the bottleneck here? I imagine the only way for me to get around that is to make changes to the schema and query?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The 21 seconds you measured for `rs.all()` is the accumulated time it takes for C* to compute and deliver the rows that make up the result set, including translation to and from the wire format. Processing the result set only takes 3 seconds, and probably has a near negligent impact on overall processing time if you do now wait for all rows to be delivered by calling `rs.all()` and instead start processing rows as soon as the first row becomes available (see "pipelining"). So start optimizing where you spent most of your time. Which is on the C* side.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I now know what I need to do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To get this to work I first have to use ResultSet::all() which really is slow

`ResultSet.all()` will fetch **all rows** using server-side **paging**. You can control the page size with `statement.setFetchSize()`

> Is there any faster way I can process each row of the result set?

It depends on your query, what is it ? If you're doing a Full partition scan, there is only a couple of machines doing the job but if you're fetching data from multiple partitions, you can try to parallelize them with multiple queries, one for each partition

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
ResultSet rs = this.getResultSet(); // Takes <1 second

StreamSupport.stream(
    Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(
                rs.iterator(), Spliterator.ORDERED), false)
       .parallel().forEach(this::processRow);
```

omitting the call to `rs.all()`

Hopefully, if the `ResultSet` allows to start iterating immediately, you'll be able to parallelize the processing earlier.

**Update**

After checking the source of `ResultSet` this is what I see:

method `all()` creates a new `ArrayList` and populates it, which takes 21 seconds in your case

```
List<Row> result = new ArrayList<Row>(rows.size());
for (Row row : this)
    result.add(row);
```

method `next()` implemented in the iterator polls the queue of rows instead

```
public Row next() {
    return Row.fromData(metadata, rows.poll());
}
```

That means data processing does not need to wait 21 seconds before starting to work on the first row.

Comment: Implementing your first suggestion still takes >20 seconds to process the rows. It seems almost as if in the back-end, the threads aren't able to read from the ResultSet at the same time.

Comment: I see. Sorry to hear that. It is not the problem of parallelism in processing. I'm sure it's working alright. It's just obtaining rows from the database is too slow. According to Amdahl's law https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law, the overall speedup is tiny when a parallel portion of chained calculations is small in relation to sequential one.

Answer (score 1):

Had almost same result as author described.
My solution was setting FetchSize to much greater value. As i read default is 5000. And get all and iterate over it took ~25secs for me. With .setFetchSize(50000) iterate takes 0.8 seconds. I don`t even believe it still. Iterating with simple foreach loop

My code :

```
String sql = "...."
prepearedSql = session.prepare(sql);
Statement statement = prepearedSql.bind().setValues(...).setFetchSize(50000);
ResultSet result = session.execute(statement);
for (Row row : result)
    {...
```